React Native Maps crashing when data is refetched onRegionChangeComplete
I update the map view by scrolling, which fires the handleRegionChange callback.
For some reason, if I don't add if (!data.length) return null, first render won't render the markers (understandable because there's no data yet). When the data does resolve, it doesn't trigger a rerender of the markers. If I scroll on the map it also crashes Expo
Unfortunately, if I add this, the whole map rerenders every time I want to  I get quite a janky experience with the MapMarkers rendering on the map, and the whole map rerenders.
I think I'm missing something, but not quite sure what it is.  I've tried creating a <MapMarkers mapViewRegion={mapViewRegion} /> component where the data fetching is isolated to the MapMarkers, to no avail.
function MapViewWithMarkers({ location }: { location: LocationObject }) {
  const mapRef = useRef<MapView>(null);

  const [mapViewRegion, setMapViewRegion] = useState<Region>({
    latitude: location.coords.latitude,
    longitude: location.coords.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.015,
    longitudeDelta: 0.015,
  });

  const handleRegionChange = (region: Region) => {
    setMapViewRegion(region);
  };

  const { data, isLoading } = trpc.venues.useQuery({ lat: mapViewRegion.latitude, lon: mapViewRegion.longitude, limit: 10 });

  // if (!data?.length) return null;

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        region={mapViewRegion}
        showsPointsOfInterest={false}
        onRegionChangeComplete={handleRegionChange}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", flex: 1 }}
        loadingEnabled={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={true}
      >
        {data?.map((venue) => (
          <MapMarker
            key={venue.id}
            identifier={venue.id.toString()}
            coordinate={{ latitude: Number(venue.latitude), longitude: Number(venue.longitude) }}
            title={venue.name}
            description={`${venue.address}`}
          />
        ))}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}

